# Php file loaded using ajax won't use database includes declared in main page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, php-include

Honestly I am new to ajax but I am comfortable with php. Now I need to make a menu which loads some info about the user into the main page via ajax.

The info is fetched from a database, (via includes) done in the main page, which works fine. But some fields that I have to display in the new page loaded with ajax does not work with the same database connections. 
In turn, the page loaded using ajax uses all the CSS styles with no problems, which are only declared in the main page.

In turn if I include the sam connection path into the php file loaded with ajax than it works, but this means loading all includes twice!?

I think about ajax like php includes, that gets included into the page upon request and can access the same resources within the main page, but maybe I am wrong.

main page:

```
<?php 
include_once 'db_connection.php'; 
include_once 'some_querys.php'; 
?>

<?php 'Your age' . echo $age; ?> //works



<!-- here I will load additional info about the user upon request -->
<!-- it loads successfully all hardcoded data, but can't access php variables from main page  -->

<div class="ajax_container"></div>
```

file loaded via ajax:

```
<div class="content-box">
<p class="title-box">More Info</p>
<ul>
<li>School: <?php echo $school ?></li>
<li>License: <?php echo $license ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Page executed with ajax-request knows **nothing** about other requests.

Comment: Than I guess it behaves similar to an iframe.